# Unsafe coerce and more efficient Agda code (-ftrust-me-im-agda)

Tags: compiler-construction, haskell, agda

On the Agda mailing list, Conor McBride asked:

> is there any way to get hold of
>   operations like a putative
>
> ```
>    trustFromJust :: Maybe x -> x
> ```
>
> which doesn't actually check for Just and Goes Wrong (in Milner's
>   sense) if fed Nothing?

Agda might prove Maybe a == Just1 a, and the intermediate constructor for the sum type could be eliminated.

I can think of approaches using unsafeCoerce# or unpackClosure#, but does anyone else have thoughts?

```
import GHC.Prim

trustFromJust :: Maybe x -> x
trustFromJust x = y
    where Just1 y = unsafeCoerce# x

data Just1 a = Just1 a
```

though this segfaults (single constructor types can avoid some of the closure overhead). The core looks ok though:

```
main2 =
  case (Data.Maybe.Just @ Type.Integer main3)
       `cast`
       (CoUnsafe
         (Data.Maybe.Maybe Type.Integer)
         (Just1 Type.Integer)
               :: Data.Maybe.Maybe Type.Integer
                    ~
                  Just1 Type.Integer)
  of _ { Just1 y_aeb ->
  $wshowsPrec 0 y_aeb ([] @ Char)
```

Comment: Interestingly, your code runs in GHCi. Though it indeed segfaults when compiling it.

Comment: Maybe has `Just` as its second-listed constructor, and Just1 has `Just1` as its first - doesn't that mean they'll get different thunk return vector offsets?  And in either case, having to construct a `Maybe` box just to unpack it seems like it would have the same overhead no matter whether you unpack it using unsafeCoerce or fromJust, wouldn't it?

Comment: If you add a dummy constructor in front of the `Just1` constructor, the `unsafeCoerce#` will not result in a segfault. I don't know of this is just because because the offsets now match or also because the data type is now also a sum type.

Comment: @Tom Lokhorst: Adding a dummy constructor in front of `Just1` makes the type identical to `Maybe` up to renaming, so segfault becomes impossible.  Anyway, I think that it is because the offsets match, because using `data MyMaybe a = MyJust a | MyNothing` instead of `Maybe` in the original example seems to produce the correct result.

Comment: Yes, the closures now have different layouts. The challenge is to help match them up safely. Help us, Simon Marlow, you're our only hope!

Comment: The problem is pointer-tagging: the representation of `Just x` is a pointer with 2 in its low bits, whereas `Just1 x` is a pointer with 1 in its low bits.  The case continuation for a single-constructor datatype assumes that the tag bits are 1, and takes that into account when accessing the fields.

Comment: Using a version of `Maybe` with the constructors reversed, so that `Just` has tag 1, is a legitimate workaround.

Comment: Perhaps it would make sense to implement a pragma or a compiler flag for this sort of purpose.  {-# PRAGMA FailureIsProvablyImpossibleHere #-}, or just like Don suggested "-ftrust-me-im-agda".  Seems like there are some optimization passes that could be added if you are willing to assert that pattern match failure really is impossible.

Comment: @mokus: Or something like `unsafeUndefined :: a` which tells the compiler that if the value of this expression is needed, the program is allowed to go wrong (segfault, evaluate to any value, throw any exception, do something funny with a nasal demon and so on).

Comment: Thinking about it, I am not sure if `trustFromJust` is ever needed in the ideal world.  If an Agda compiler can prove that a certain expression of type `maybe Integer` always evaluates to a `Just` value, is there any reason why it cannot convert the expression to another expression of type `Integer` before it passes the program to a Haskell compiler?  (I know almost nothing about Agda or the theory of programming languages in general, so excuse me if this is a stupid question.)

Comment: @Tsuyoshi Ito - the expression may only be known to be `Just` on certain code paths, so at some point a runtime conversion will be required.

Comment: @Ganesh Sittampalam: Ah, I see.  Thank you for the explanation.

Comment: @Don, this question is sitting at the top of the Unanswered page, devoid of life. Could @Simon or someone enter their comment as an answer, so that could it at least be upvoted (if not accepted) and so move off the unanswered list?

Comment: viewed 501 times!  No answers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since this is a research question, we've got a few possible ways forward, but they all come down to:

- Play tricks reversing the tag bits of Maybe